# Passing Variable from Asterisk Dialplan to AGI perl script

Tags: perl, asterisk, agi

I am trying to pass a variable from the Asterisk Dialplan to a perl script using the AGI. I am now to this and am very confused at to how exactly this works. Right now in my dialplan I have this:

```
exten=>1122,1,Answer
exten=>1122,n,Read(digit)
exten=>1122,n,agi(/home/steve/Desktop/testperlping.pl,${digit})
exten=>1122,n,Hangup()
```

I want a user to dial the extension 1122, then enter a number from 1-10, and have the number they entered passed into perl using the AGI.

My perl script is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
$|=1;

use Net::Ping;
use Asterisk::AGI;

$AGI = new Asterisk::AGI;

my %input = $AGI->ReadParse();

***I think I need something here***

$AGI->verbose("$numbertheytypedintophone"); #This will display the entered number back to the CLI.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `my ($digit) = @ARGV;`?

Comment: that doesn't seem to help

Comment: try looking for setvariable or similar method in your perl AGI api,   see https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/AGICommand_set+variable

Answer (score 0):

I am using Asterisk::FastAGI(which is recomended for perl integration) and code looks like this:

```
my $dst = $self->param('dst');
```

For Asterisk::AGI it have be(i just read AGI.pm source):

```
my $digits=$input{'arg_1'};
```

I higly recomend you read source code of module if you have any issues, will be MUCH faster.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a part of a dialplan

```
exten => _X.,1,NoOp(${PJSIP_HEADER(read,To)})
exten => _X.,n,Set(FirstTo=${CUT(PJSIP_HEADER(read,To),:,2)})
exten => _X.,n,Set(TO_DID=${CUT(FirstTo,@,1)})
exten => _X.,n,Set(client_number=${CALLERID(num)})
exten => _X.,n,AGI(check_nr.agi,,${client_number})
exten => _X.,n,Set(First_check=${first_ani})
```

Note the double comma on the agi script

The script part which will use the client_number value

```
  (my $empty_field,  my $data ) = @ARGV;
   my @data_array = split /--/, $data;                  
   my $callerid   = $data_array[0];
```

The split part is if you have multiple parameters like

```
AGI(check_nr.agi,,${client_number}--${second}--${third})
```

In this case would be

```
  (my $empty_field,  my $data ) = @ARGV;
   my @data_array = split /--/, $data;                  
   my $callerid   = $data_array[0]; 
   my $second     = $data_array[1]; 
   my $third      = $data_array[2];
```

To pass the variable back to the asterisk dialplan you should use:

```
print "SET VARIABLE first_ani $first_ani\n";
```

Full perl script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# Modules to use
use strict ;
use warnings;
use Config::IniFiles;
use DBI;
use sigtrap;
use sigtrap qw(handler my_handler normal-signals stack-trace error-signals);


                   my $cfg = Config::IniFiles -> new( -file => '/etc/my_file.ini' );
                   my $dbinst = $cfg -> val('AST', 'DBINST');
                   my $dbhost = $cfg -> val('AST', 'DBHOST');
                   my $dbuser = $cfg -> val('AST', 'DBUSER');
                   my $dbpass = $cfg -> val('AST', 'DBPASS');
                   
                   my $dbhA  = DBI->connect( "dbi:mysql:$dbinst:$dbhost",$dbuser,$dbpass, {RaiseError => 0,PrintError => 1,AutoCommit => 0,}) or die $DBI::errstr;     



########################################### Pass data from asterisk channel to perl script ##########################################
  (my $empty_field,  my $data ) = @ARGV;
   my @data_array = split /--/, $data;                  
   my $callerid   = $data_array[0];

########################################### Pass data from asterisk channel to perl script ##########################################


        my $sthA = $dbhA->prepare( "select  ani,
                                            numero,
                                            data_ultima_modifica
                                    from my_table
                                    where numero = ?
                                    ORDER BY data_ultima_modifica DESC "); 
           $sthA->bind_param( 1, $callerid ); 
           $sthA->execute();
        my $sthArows=$sthA->rows;

            if ($sthArows > 0) 
            {
              my @aryA                  = $sthA->fetchrow_array;
              my $ani                   = $aryA[0];
              my $numero                = $aryA[1];
              my $data_ultima_modifica  = $aryA[2];
            
                   print "SET VARIABLE first_ani  $first_ani \n";
             }
            $sthA->finish();    


 
################## Close DB Connection##################
                warn $DBI::errstr if $DBI::err;
                $dbhA->commit(); 
                $dbhA->disconnect();
################## Close DB Connection##################
```